# I need to print the values from the web service from one screen to another screen in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display the values from the web service from one screen to another screen,but i am unable to print those values on the next screen.

Actually my emulator is getting run,but showing only the empty screen

Here is my source for reference,please find it and let me know the solution.

**Main_WB.java**

```
public class Main_WB extends Activity 
{
EditText edt1,edt2;
  //    TextView txt_1;

Button btn;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    edt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        getTMSChart(edt1.getText().toString(),edt2.getText().toString());
        Intent myint = new Intent(Main_WB.this,ResultActivity.class);
        startActivity(myint);
    }     
    });
  }

 private void getTMSChart(String FromDate,String ToDate)
 {
 //txt_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

 System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");        
 SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);        

 envelope.dotNet = true;

 String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";
 String METHOD = "GetTMSChart";

 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);        
 request.addProperty("FromDate", FromDate);               
 request.addProperty("ToDate", ToDate);

 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

 try 
 {
    androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + METHOD, envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    SoapObject root =  (SoapObject) ((SoapObject)(result).getProperty(0)).getProperty("NewDataSet");
    int tablesCount = root.getPropertyCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < tablesCount; i++)
    {
       SoapObject table = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
       int propertyCount = table.getPropertyCount();

       int[] ord = new int[propertyCount];
       int[] fre = new int[propertyCount];
       int[] margin = new int[propertyCount];

    for (int j = 0; j < propertyCount; j++)
    {   
        String x,y;

        int orderNo = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No"));
        int freightRate = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Freight_Rate"));
        int marginPercent = Integer.parseInt(table.getPropertyAsString("Margin_Percent"));

    //  String orderNo =  table.getPropertyAsString("Order_No");

        ord[j] = orderNo;
        fre[j] = freightRate;
        margin[j]= marginPercent;

        x = ord.toString();
        y = fre.toString();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Main_WB.this, ResultActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("gotonextpage", x);
        startActivity(myIntent);

        // whatever you do with these values
          }                   
       }
    }   
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    }   
    }      }
```

**ResultActivity.java**

```
 public class ResultActivity extends Activity 
 {
String str;
TextView txtv;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main1);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null)
{   
 str = extras.getString("goto_next_page");
 }
else
{   
}

txtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVw);
txtv.setText(str);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AsynkTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

And on `onPostExecute` I would start the activity.

That networking mixed with UI it to mess for me, does it run in Android 4 at all? - you should get an exception there with no network on UI thread or something like that, forgot the exception name. Anyway, try to separate the network and UI layers.

Also calling an asmx, I needed to se somewhere - forgot where - a param to true: isDotNet or similar the prope name.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("gotonextpage", "default");
```

instead of

```
getIntent().getExtras();
```

in the resultActivity. Note that you have to use the same key you used to put data, to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're calling your web service on the UI thread. That's a big no-no.

Second, your names don't match. You're setting the extra as "gotonextpage", but then trying to retrieve it in the second activity as "goto_next_page".

Comment: Even though if i change "goto_next_page" to gotonextpage its showing the same empty page....what to do?

Comment: Well, are you sure there was anything in the string to show in the first place? You should use the Log class to send the information to logcat before launching the second activity, and then use Log again in the second activity to verify it matches what you expect. Also, I'd put some placeholder text on the TextView, just so you can verify that it's not something silly like black text on a black background.

Comment: Actually i am trying to create a bar chart in android,but i need to get the x and y values from the web service by consuming it...so here i am struggling to pass the values from the web service to the BarGarph() function,will you please make me clear about this concept,actually im doing android projects lonely with no help,will you please help me....

Comment: You need to log. My theory is that x == "" - an empty string (otherwise you'd probably get a null pointer exception). I take it you're using http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ for your soap calls? Set androidHttpTransport.debug = true;. After your call(), you can then log the values of androidHttpTransport.requestDump and androidHttpTransport.responseDump.